# How to Make Header Location 301 in PHP via Coding

Tags: php, redirect, http-headers

i have these codes work fine `echo $data[''.$itag.'']['url']` for get link url but when i use this codes for redirect 301 header location this code is not work please any one tell what i can do with this code for get 301 header location

`<?php header("Location: "echo $data[''.$itag.'']['url']"", true, 301); exit();?>`

please suggest for this codes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php 
    header("Location: ".$data[$itag]['url'], true, 301); 
    exit();
?>
```